# Losing hover when hovering over text

Tags: arrays, hover, raphael

I am trying to hover a set with a path and text in it in Raphael. On hover I need to change only the color of the path, not the text. Currently my code does not know which set is being hovered and changes the last element of the array only.

This is probably a silly mistake, but I am stumped :)

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kiaaanabal/znacD/1/

```
    function hexHoverIn() {
  hex.attr({fill: '#00411a'});
  console.log("Hovering Set" + i);
} //hexHoverIn

function hexHoverOut() {
  hex.attr({gradient: '70-#004838-#028151'});
} //hexHoverOut 

var hexArray = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < hexData.length; i++) {
  var hex = paper.path(hexData[i].pathData);
  hex.attr({rotation: hexData[i].rotation, gradient: '70-#004838-#028151', stroke: '#CFD4D7', 'stroke-width': 5, cursor: 'pointer' });

  var hexText = paper.text(hexData[i].xPos, hexData[i].yPos, hexData[i].text);
  hexText.attr({fill: '#fff', 'font-size': 10, 'font-family': 'Arial', cursor: 'pointer'});

  hexArray[i] = paper.set();
  hexArray[i].push(hex, hexText).hover(hexHoverIn, hexHoverOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't finish the implementation, please see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m4Z2K/ which display with the correct effect yon want  :)

Mostly my changes are:

1.Declare a hashmap before your for-loop, this is to save all the path object

```
var hexObjectMap ={}; // maintain a hashmap for all the path object
```

2.Use (see [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data) for Element.data() API details) data() to save the id in each object

```
hex.data('key',i); // save a identifier in each object
```

3.Save the path object in the map after hex is created

```
hexObjectMap[i] = hex; // save each path object to map
```

4.In hexHoverIn() and hexHoverOut(), get the id out from the object (**this** will be the path object user currently hover on)

```
var key = this.data('key'); // retrieve the 'key' in this path object
```

and replace **hex** with **hexObjectMap[key]** since **hex** only stay reference to the last path object you created.

```
hexObjectMap[key].attr({fill:'#00411a'});
```

Let me know if you have future questions, enjoy.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at this! You solved part of it, just using **this** causes the hexagon to lose its hover when hovering over the text (at least that is what I think was causing it).

Anyway, we ended up finding another solution, but I will take a look at your solution!

Thanks again!

Comment: oh ya, that's a tricky part, in my web application I get around of this by attaching hover effect for the text object as well: hexText.hover(textHoverIn,textHoverOut), and you also need save data in hextText to be used in hover function.